# Nominal GDP calculations given CPI and Real GDP

Tags: gdp

How can I project or estimate nominal GDP for the years 2024 and 2025 when I have real GDP forecasts and CPI forecasts up to 2025, but only have actual data for nominal GDP up to 2023?

Currently, my approach involves calculating the ratio between the GDP deflator and CPI up to 2023. Then, using a spline method, I fill in the next two years of this ratio. Next, I apply this ratio to the CPI forecasts to create a GDP deflator forecast for 2024 and 2025. Finally, I multiply the GDP deflator forecast by the real GDP forecasts to obtain the nominal GDP forecasts. Are there any alternative methods or considerations that I should take into account for a more accurate estimation given the data that I possess?